# How to copy data from a field in one table to another in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, inner-join

In postgresql I've got two tables:

**message**

```
id
source
time
```

**message_detail**

```
id
message_id
text
time
```

I now want to copy all values of `message.time` to `message_detail.time`.

How would I do this?

Comment: Take a look at examples(bottom of page) here [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want the update/join syntax:

```
update message_detail md
set time = m.time
from message m
where m.id = md.message_id
```

This assumes a one-to-many (or one-to-one) relationship between messages and details, where several details may refer to a single message, through foreign key relationship `message_detail(message_id)` => `message(id)`.